# How to check if device is turned off

Tags: power, led

Is there a way to check if the Pi is off, without looking at the chip itself but with a LED or something like that.

Comment: You could attach an LED to one of the GPIO pins. On boot, run a script that turns the GPIO pin on. When the raspberry is turned of the led should turn off as well. Although the led might be turned of a few seconds before the pi is done shutting down completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should define "turned off"

you may easily realize there's no power when red LED is dark. and when only red LED is shining, the CPU is most likely halted and the system is stopped. sorry i cannot offer any help besides that without knowing what exactly you're looking for.